# Swi-prolog bug weird output

Tags: prolog

I have following program:

```
filter([],_What,[]).

filter(List,What,Output):-
    not(select(What-Val,List,Rest)), 
    filter([],What,Output).

filter(List,What,[Val|Output]):-
    select(What-Val,List,Rest),
    filter(Rest,What,Output).
```

I don't understand why following query:

```
filter([age-90, age-80,age-80],age,Output).
```

outputs:

```
Output = "ZPP"
```

I have latest version of SWI-prolog ( 7.4.2 ), and have mac with El Captain (10.11.6).

I have tried guitracer, and it builds list [90,80,80] but outputs "ZPP"
I have no idea why it does that.

SWISH online prolog outputs [90,80,80], so it must be something with SWI-Prolog.

**EDIT**

It seems that it converts number into characters 90=Z, 80=P, etc...

**Why does it do this?**

Comment: Yes, in SWI Prolog, `"ZPP"` represents the "string" (list) of codes for `Z`, `P`, and `P`. So they're equivalent. Not sure what mode you have your SWI Prolog set to that causes it to default do displaying `[90, 80, 80]` as a string. Perhaps more importantly, you have at least two singleton variables and your query doesn't terminate (infinitely generates the solution `Output = [90, 80, 80]`).

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell how it got loaded, but this behaviour can be triggered by `portray_text(true)`:

```
6 ?- A = [90,80,80].
A = [90,80,80].

7 ?- portray_text(true).
true.

8 ?- A = [90,80,80].
A = "ZPP".
```

The idea is that if you process text as lists of character codes the output is hard to read.  portray_text/1 enables a portray/1 hook that tries to interpret
a list of integers as a list of character codes and if successful prints the result as a string.

The GUI tracer can be configured to do this, but I don't think this is the default.

Comment: This seems to be the problem, setting it to true isn't working on mac, it still outputs numbers. I tested it on windows swi-prolog and it outputs characters correctly when portray_text(true).

Comment: Works fine on my Mac.   Portability of this feature is also unrelated to this question.  Start a new question and include details (version, installed from binary, Macports, Homebrew, etc.  using in a terminal or as app, etc.)